# Bash Autocompletion with multiple argument values per argument

Tags: bash, autocomplete, git-bash

I'm trying to implement tab completion for the first time - it has to work in GIT Bash and its for a python script that i wrote (done with `argparser`)

The script basically has two arguments `--option_a` and `--option_b` and they accept both single and multiple argument values, e.g. `script --option_a steak` or `script --option_a steak burger pizza` are both valid. There's still a set of choices to choose from though, so you cannot enter whatever you like.

I already got most of it done:

### What's already done

```sh
OPTION_A_VALUES="bread pizza steak burger"
OPTION_B_VALUES="apple banana"

_autocomplete () {                
  COMPREPLY=()   
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  local prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

  case "$prev" in
   "--option_a")
       COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$OPTION_A_VALUES" -- $cur ) )  
       return 0 
       ;;
  "--option_b")
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$OPTION_B_VALUES" -- $cur ) )
        return 0 
       ;;
 esac

  if [[ ${cur} == -* ]]
    then
      COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "--option_a --option_b" -- $cur ) )
    return 0
  fi
}

complete -o nospace -F _autocomplete script
```

`script` is the alias for the python script.

- ```sh
  $ script --option_a bur<TAB>
  ```

  This evaluates to `script --option_a burger`. Excellent!

### The problem

Basically what i still need to do is supporting autocompletion for all the possible argument values - currently it stops after completing one:

- ```sh
  $ script --option_a burger pi<TAB>
  ```

  This does **not** evaluate to `script --option_a burger pizza` yet :( Bad!

Of course, after completing to `pizza` and typing `--<TAB><TAB>` the script should again suggest `--option_a --option_b`

Any help on how to modify my autocomplete script to make this work would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
_autocomplete () {
  COMPREPLY=()
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  local prev=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}

  if [[ ${cur} == -* ]]
    then
      COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "--option_a --option_b" -- $cur ) )
    return 0
  fi

  case "$prev" in
   --option_a|bread|pizza|steak|burger)
       COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$OPTION_A_VALUES" -- $cur ) )
       return 0
       ;;
   --option_b|apple|banana)
       COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$OPTION_B_VALUES" -- $cur ) )
       return 0
       ;;
 esac

}
```

The idea is

If the `cur` starts with `-`, the `compgen` gets `option_a option_b` immediately

If the `prev` is one of `--option_a bread pizza steak burger`, it gets the values again